# Why is my zsh tab completion slow on commands but not directories?

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I am using zsh with completion turned on. When I try to tab-complete, sometimes the command hangs for a long time. After a few seconds it completes and correctly presents my options. On the other hand, if I interrupt it with Ctrl-C, I get the following message:

```
Killed by signal in _path_commands after 2s
```

If I try to tab-complete directories (e.g. in `ls`) it works just fine, there is no lag.

Note that I am running on Windows using WSL2, though I can vaguely recall it happening on other systems, too. Haven't gone back to confirm, but when I just tested  on my server, I couldn't reproduce it there, so it's something about the environment.

Comment: Could it be that one of the elements in your `path` points to a Network share? In particular on Windows. this could explain the delay. Another point worth to check: Do you also see the delay immediately after doing a `rehash`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Providing an answer for my own question to share what I found. If others have a better idea, I would love to accept their answer. However, when googling I could not find anything on this error (not helped by zsh's obscure syntax making it about as easy to google as perl expressions).

The **tl;dr** solution is as follows: Run `unsetopt pathdirs` and the issue should go away. Put it in your `~/.zshrc` and it should be resolved. What follows is the explanation.

Turning on tracing for `_path_commands` to see where it hangs: `autoload -t _path_commands`:

```
+_path_commands:46> ret=0
+_path_commands:51> [[ -o path_dirs ]]
+_path_commands:52> local -a path_dirs
```

So let's have a look at that function via `which _path_commands` (note you need to do a completion once for zsh to load it). I'll provide the relevant snippet:

```
        if [[ -o path_dirs ]]
        then
                local -a path_dirs
                path_dirs=(${^path}/*(/N:t))
                (( ${#path_dirs} )) && _wanted path-dirs expl 'directory in path' compadd "$@" -a path_dirs && ret=0
                if [[ $PREFIX$SUFFIX = */* ]]
                then
                        _wanted commands expl 'external command' _path_files -W path -g '*(*)' && ret=0
                fi
        fi
```

The last line we get when it hangs is `local -a path_dirs` which just defines an empty array. That's likely not it, but if I execute the next command it hangs for a long time: `path_dirs=(${^path}/*(/N:t))`. Good luck googling that if you're not familiar with the language. I'll explain:

- We are creating an array with `( ... )`
- We reference the parameter `$path`
- We turn on `RC_EXPAND_PARAM`  with the `^` chracter `${^path}`, see [14.3 Parameter Expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion). It's not our culprit so I'll skip the explanation. The only bit to understand is that we have an array here.
- Do globbing inside each directory via `/*`. This is the same as if you did this on your command line: `ls *`, for example. Except here it does it for *all elements* of the array, like a loop. A good culprit, but if we try `echo ${^path}/*` it's still very quick.
- Lastly we add three [glob qualifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation), essentially *filters* on the results of that expansion:

  - `/` only returns directories
  - `N` sets `nullglob`, basically "remove empty elements"
  - `:t` sets the [modifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) to remove the full path and leave only the `basename` output.

If we play around with the full expression e.g. `${^path}/*(/N:t)` we notice that it's only slow if the `/` character is present. Removing it makes everything fast. With some additional debugging you can even find what's slow, e.g. write a loop and see when it hangs:

```
for item in $path; do echo "${item}: " ${item}/*(/); done
```

In my case I notice it hanging on a lot of Windows paths (`/mnt/c/Windows/system32`, for example).  At this point I **gave up**: I don't know why this expansion is so slow for Windows paths and I don't know how to debug it or do some form of "caching" that speeds it up (it might just be slow due to WSL filesystem issues).

Instead, notice how there is a condition: `if [[ -o path_dirs ]]` before entering this code path? The [conditional test](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Conditional-Expressions.html) `-o` checks for an option, i.e. if `path_dirs` is set. This is described in the [options manual](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#Description-of-Options):

> PATH_DIRS (-Q)

> Perform a path search even on command names with slashes in them. Thus if ‘/usr/local/bin’ is in the user’s path, and he or she types ‘X11/xinit’, the command ‘/usr/local/bin/X11/xinit’ will be executed (assuming it exists). Commands explicitly beginning with ‘/’, ‘./’ or ‘../’ are not subject to the path search. This also applies to the ‘.’ and source builtins.

If we can live without this feature (I think I can), we can stop here: Simply turn it off, e.g. via `unsetopt pathdirs` and call it a day. Once that's done, this code branch is no longer executed and the problem goes away.

Comment: Excellent analysis. FWIW, This type of problem (especially that god awful glob expansion) is why I stopped using Zsh over a decade ago. All POSIX shells suck but Zsh sucks hard. I've written a couple of blog articles highlighting similar problems I have encountered. Do yourself a favor and switch to a sane, modern alternative, shell like Fish or Elvish.

Comment: Just read your blog posts, you make good points. Maybe I'll consider another shell in the future. For now though I'll hopefully be spared too many such adventures ;-)